# How to convert coodinates to geom in SQL and see them as geom in R?

Tags: r, sql-server

I converted coordinates in SQL to geographic type of POINT:

```
geography::Point(c.Latitude,c.Longitude,4326).ToString()
```

In R, I can see that this column is of type *char*, not *geom* even though I converted it properly.
I also tried conversion without using *.ToString()* but there was an error in this column when I executed SQL code in R. In SQL it showed my sth like this as POINT:

```
0xE6100000010CC2BEBAEEA0824940F37CC85CBDE33040
```

Is it possible at all to convert data to geom type in SQL and see them as geom in R? Or maybe I should do this only in R?

Comment: What does the data look like when you do use ToString?

Comment: POINT (18.6651 50.2285)

Comment: Then follow @r2evans advice below using the `sf` package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60927929/querying-sql-server-geospatial-data-from-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. If your table currently has two float fields named `Latitude` and `Longitude`, I suggest you pull them directly (as `numeric` in R), and then do whatever `sf::` or `sp::` work you need in R.

   ```r
   DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select c.Longitude, c.Latitude from ...")
   ```
2. Import into `sf` objects in R. I'll adapt sample code provided https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15:

   ```r
   con <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
   # demonstration of the version I'm using, just for comparison
   DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select @@version as ver")
   #                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ver
   # 1 Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64) \n\tJul  5 2017 23:41:17 \n\tCopyright (c) Microsoft Corporation\n\tStandard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: )\n


   out <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "DECLARE @g geography;   
   SET @g = geography::Point(47.65101, -122.34901, 4326)  
   (SELECT @g.ToString() as point) union all (select @g.ToString() as point) ;  ")

   out
   #                         point
   # 1 POINT (-122.34901 47.65101)
   # 2 POINT (-122.34901 47.65101)
   ```

   From here, you can either parse out the components if you just need the numbers:

   ```r
   strcapture("\\b([-+]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\s+([-+]?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\b", out$point, proto = list(lon=0, lat=0))
   #       lon      lat
   # 1 122.349 47.65101
   # 2 122.349 47.65101
   ```

   or you can import them directly as an `sf` object:

   ```r
   sf::st_as_sfc(out$point)
   # Geometry set for 2 features 
   # geometry type:  POINT
   # dimension:      XY
   # bbox:           xmin: -122.349 ymin: 47.65101 xmax: -122.349 ymax: 47.65101
   # CRS:            NA
   # POINT (-122.349 47.65101)
   # POINT (-122.349 47.65101)
   ```

And from there, convert it to the R-specific format you need for local processing.

Comment: Thank you. I have additional question - what is faster for large amount of data? Importing 'float' coordinates and convert to sf in R or execute code on server side (geography::Point) and create sf object?

Comment: I would expect that numbers are theoretically faster, but you should also consider any overhead (on either side) of conversion. I expect that both routines would be fairly efficient, so time them yourself given your typical (or most-likely "worst case", if that makes sense) scenario. For smaller data (1000s of rows), I'd think it'd be a wash.